# Facebook application ( count friends registered )

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

Using JS SDK for facebook, is there a way to count number of friends (of currently logged in user) that are also using my application ?? I found this query online

```
SELECT uid FROM user 
WHERE user.uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ?) 
AND is_app_user = 1
```

But I don't understand it, and I don't know what to put instead of '?'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It retrieves `uid` of friends of the user, specified by `?`, that are also users of your application.

So instead of `?` just put the current user's id.

Detailed information about: [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) and [friend](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) fql tables

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I tried that and it gives me "Parser error: unexpected 'uid' at position 26"

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the uid of the currently logged on user, just make use of me()